# Make specific color for a row based on row's property

Tags: angular

I have a requirement to highlight rows with specific color based on its attribute.
For example, let's say I am displaying employee records and all employees whose highest education column is not null then show it with green

I have the existing code as following in the corresponding employee.component.html file

```
   <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let record of employees">
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
    <td>{{record.designation}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="record.qualification" bgcolor="green">{{record.qualification}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

so as of now, only a specific column is colored but the requirement is to color the whole row?
I am using Angular 10.x.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the styles to the `<tr>` (Table Row) element instead of the specific TD Element. An example implementation could look like this:

```html
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let record of employees" [class.green]="!!record.qualification">
     <td>{{record.name}}</td>
     <td>{{record.designation}}</td>
     <td *ngIf="record.qualification" bgcolor="green">{{record.qualification}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this example, the "condition" I'm using is `!!record.qualification` which will be `true` if that property exists, but you could replace that with whatever your condition should be.

With the `class` method, your CSS file would look something like this (actually turns the row green)

```css
.green {
   background-color: green;
}
```

I also decided to use `class.green` because it would allow you to style your row even more if you wanted to add different styling.

If you don't want to use CSS classes, you could use a different property, for example:

`[style.background-color]="!!record.qualification ? 'green' : 'unset'"`

Comment: Can you please confirm if the record can be referred to as suggested
<tr *ngFor="let record of employees" [class.green]="!!record.qualification">
In fact I first thought the same but got the error "record not available or cannot be referenced"

Comment: It should be able to. If it seems to not work, you could try doing the for loop on an outer ng-container like: `<ng-container *ngFor="let record of employees"><tr>...</tr></ng-container>`

Comment: I want to avoid using the same condition for individual tr tag so loking for something at the outer level.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem in the following manner

1. declared the required changes in CSS as

   .error-row {
   background:red;
   color:white;
   }
2. Changed the component.html file
   from

to

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of employees" [ngClass]="{'error-row': record.qualification}">
```